# asp.net ajax call fails after a certain time: networkError

Tags: ajax, authentication

simple json Request where myUrl is a valid URL:

```
 var request = $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: async
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        formatData(data);            
        callback(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        handleJsonFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown,'Error on making chartData Operation!');
    });
```

The first time I call this, everything works fine. But after a certain time (one hour) I get the following exception: **NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'myUrl'**

I use no session in my project (sessionState mode='Off')

The authentication happens via WSFederationAuthenticationModule.

I'm still authorized because after refreshing the page, I'm still logged in.

Am I missing something? I think it's a knowledge gap because I never had to do something with this type of authentication and so I don't know what really happens in the background....

thx
©a-x-i